# How can I set a specific IP range for NFS exports file?

Tags: linux, ip, nfs, export, address

For example, I want to set an allowed IP range from 192.168.0.12 to 192.168.0.20.

Would it require me to input all the IP addresses on that one line? Or is there an easier way to set this specific range?

Answer (score 5):

in your exports file you can put many addresses for a single share

```
/SHARE 192.168.0.12/30(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) 192.168.0.26/30(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

this is just an example, you can put every single IP if you want instead of netblocks, or use hostnames.